# How to access object from _config.yml with reference from post in Jekyll?

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

For each post I want to have author and a link to his page. So I need to have username in post like:

```
---
title: "Some Post"
author: user_x
---
```

and have something like this in _config.yml

```
users:
 -
   user_x:
       url: "/some-url"
       name: "Full Name"
```

to have mapping user -> url and name, and how can I display that in a post? I've try this:

```
<a href="">{{ site.users[ post.author ].name }}</a>
```

but got object instead of name value. I've also try to not use `-` after users but go the same object as result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`page.author`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables), not `post.author`:

```
<a href="">{{ site.users[page.author].name }}</a>
```

Your Yaml should look something like this:

```
users:
  user_x:
    url: "/some-url"
    name: "Full Name"
  user_y:
    url: "/some-other-url"
    name: "A Different Name"
```

You might want to use [`assign`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/variable-tags#assign) if you’re using several values from the user:

```
{% assign user = site.users[page.author] %}

<a href="{{ user.url }}">{{ user.name }}</a>
```

Comment: Hey, do you know by a chance, if there's something like `assign` in Angular.js?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small plugin for that:

```
module Jekyll
  module AuthorData
    def author_name(username)
      users = @context.registers[:site].config['users']
      users.detect { |hash| hash.keys.include? username }.values.first['name']
    end

    def author_url(username)
      users = @context.registers[:site].config['users']
      users.detect { |hash| hash.keys.include? username }.values.first['url']
    end

    def author(username, value)
      users = @context.registers[:site].config['users']
      users.detect { |hash| hash.keys.include? username }.values.first[value]
    end

  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::AuthorData)
```

Now, inside `index.html` (that's the page I tested), I was able to use the following code to get the name and url of the author:

```
{% post.author | author_name %}
{% post.author | author_url %}
```

Or, you could use the generic filter:

```
{% post.author | author: 'name' %}
```

The YAML front-matter:

author: 'user_x'

The `_config.yml` file:

```
users:
  - user_x:
      url: '/test_x'
      name: 'User X'
  - user_y:
      url: '/test_y'
      name: 'User Y'
```

The `@context.registers` is the way Jekyll provides access to internal data of the app for use in plugins. Checkout the [protip below the filters docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#liquid-filters).

*PS: I think there is some inconsistency in the documentation there—or perhaps, on the version of Jekyll I'm using—but I wasn't able to access the site via `context` method and had to resort to using the instance variable.*

Comment: Doesn't it possible wihout writing ruby code? I've started learning Jekyll and I didn't look into plugins yet.

Comment: AFACS, no. You'd need to write the code to atleast fetch the url/name from the array of hashes (i.e., `users`).

Comment: Then it's better to create more general solution that will fetch a field from a hash, like `pluck` from underscore. Is it possible to have paramters like in Angular.js `pluck:'name'` or twig `pluck('name')`?

Comment: Yes, you can pass in parameters to the filter. Will update the answer

Comment: @jcubic Just updated the answer with another way to fetch information. The idea is that you could construct the filters anyway you want, pretty much like you could have addons on Angular's default filters.